# How to make a queue available for 3rd party systems to consume

Tags: magento2, message-queue, rabbit-mq

I need to create a message queue in Magento and expose it to the 3rd-party system. As I understand, it is required to create communication.xml, queue_publisher.xml, and queue_topology.xml files - so that I'll be able to publish there.

But how I can expose this queue to the external application to consume messages? This 3rd-party application should be able to consume it via HTTP somehow.